# Homotopy groups of spheres and differential forms

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, differential-topology, homotopy-groups-of-sphere

The only infinite homotopy groups of spheres are $\pi_n(\mathbb{S}^n)$ and $\pi_{4n-1}(\mathbb{S}^{2n})$. This is a well known result of Serre. In both cases the nontriviality of these groups can be detected using differential forms. Namely, using the degree theory in the case of $\pi_n(\mathbb{S}^n)$ and using the Hopf invariant in the case of $\pi_{4n-1}(\mathbb{S}^{2n})$. **Are there any known cases of finite non-trivial homotopy groups of spheres that can be detected with differential forms?**

There is a well known method of Pontryagin of computing homotopy groups of spheres which is based on methods of differential topology, as beautifully described in [notes](https://www3.nd.edu/~andyp/notes/HomotopySpheresLowDimTop.pdf)
by Andy Putman. However, I am more interested in the use of differential forms.

I am interested in analytical methods since I am interested in Lipschitz homotopy groups. Classical homological methods do not distinguish between Lipschitz and continuous and so analytical methods are much more adequate.

Comment: It seems to me that rather than differential forms you are using homological methods (that in their analytic incarnation might or might not be represented by differential forms). Are you interested in an answer that explains how homological methods can be used to compute the homotopy groups of spheres or are you specifically interested in applications where differential forms play a crucial role? Neither the degree nor the Hopf invariant require differential forms (and in fact I don't know how to define the latter with them, although I'll believe it is possible)

Comment: I was wondering something similar once for SU(2) bundles over spheres, where the clutching functions give torsion elements in the homotopy groups S^3

Comment: The definition of the Hopf invariant using differential forms in explained in the book by Bott and Tu, _Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology_, page 228.

Comment: I doubt it. Differential forms do not detect torsion phenomena in homotopy--they are real invariants.

Comment: @JohnKlein what if $exp(\int_{\Sigma} \omega)$ is always valued in $n^{th}$ roots of unity, for appropriate cycles $\Sigma$? (Just asking, perhaps this kind of thing is not possible...)

Comment: @DavidRoberts integration along  gives a chain map from the DeRham complex to the singular cochains (in your case with coefficients in the complex numbers. This map will not detect torsion.

However, I should have modified my original comment. If one is willing to work with twisted coefficients in a flat bundle, the there are invariants which detect torsion phenomena (in homology), for example, the analytic torsion invariant of Ray and Singer.

Comment: Bundle n-gerbes with connection are very closely related to differential cohomology and detect all integral cohomology groups.  Many differential geometric constructions, such as Chern classes, admit a refinement to bundle n-gerbes with connection.

Comment: @JohnKlein aha!

Comment: Is rational homotopy theory of any use here?

Comment: @DeaneYang In the case of homotopy groups of spheres the rational homotopy works only if the homotopy groups is infinite which is exactly the case of $\pi_n(S^n)$ and $\pi_{4n-1}(S^{2n})$, but that is covered by differential forms. Did you men Sullivan's theory?

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz, yes.